# Inkwell(ontap) Widget is not working properly?

Tags: flutter, dart, ontap

I am unable to add ontap functionality .
I tried very much to add Inkwell but same result  card is not pressing and also I tried to print within custom widget but same result..
Also I tried Wraping inkwell with Material
and wrping container with IgnorePointer

```
 Wrap(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap:onPressed,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 200,
                              child: Card(
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 200,
                                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 600?150:250,
                                      child: ClipRRect(
                                       
                                        child: Image.memory(
                                          base64Decode(Url),
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),


                        ),
                          )
                        )],
                    ),
```

```
return Container(
  child:   detail_blog(
    title:title,
    Url: image_url,
  onPressed: (){
      print("preesed");
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder)=>
blog_detail(
  image_url: image_url3,
    title: title,
    code: code,
    desc3: desc3,
    catagorie: catagorie,
    code1: code1,
    code2: code2,
    Date_time: Date_time,
    desc: desc,
    desc1: desc1, desc2: desc2,
  image_url1: image_url,
  image_url2: image_url1,
  image_url3: image_url2,
)
));
  },
  ),
);
```

Comment: what its `onPressed` ? 
 you may use it  `() => onPressed()`

Comment: it is the custom widget.   final VoidCallback onPressed;

Comment: IgnorePointer won't help you much here. I would try to wrap the InkWell in a Material Widget. This ensures that the InkWell is able to display a ripple effect. If it still doesn't, I suspect the Wrap widget somehow obscured the hitbox.

Comment: I have used gridview in code I think it causes the onpress issue if I use Listview instead of it gridview it work fine but I don't know why it create issue..

Answer (score 1):

You should use either () => or (){} in any click listener in Flutter. While you can use a function callback directly like 'onTap: functionCallback', it is still recommended to define the callback as 'Function() functionCallback'.

Comment: it is custom widget and I used onpressed in second code
  final VoidCallback onPressed;